# Rest controller for APN in spring project(push notification)

Tags: java, ios, spring, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

*MOD* - I'm struggling with APNs Service to send push notification on iOS device.
My code is:

```
try {
        ApnsService apnsService =
                APNS.newService()
                        .withCert(localCertPath, "psw")
                        //.withProductionDestination() --> why apns prod point at "gateway.push.apple.com", 2195 ???
                        .withGatewayDestination("api.push.apple.com", 443) --> is this right production endpoint? I think yes..reading official apple documentation
                        .build();
        apnsService.start();

        String payload = APNS.newPayload()
                .alertBody("test notification")
                .sound("default")
                .build();

        apnsService.push(DEVICE_TOKEN, payload);
        System.out.println("Message sent!");
        apnsService.stop();
    } catch (NetworkIOException nE) {
        nE.printStackTrace();
}
```

Response is 200 ok but problem is:

```
Message sent!
2019-10-08 15:02:17.938+0200 [com.project.pushSender] INFO  [Thread-9] [//] [c.n.a.i.ApnsConnectionImpl.run] - Exception while waiting for error code
java.io.IOException: Unexpected command byte 0
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl$1MonitoringThread.run(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:118)
```

I've tried also with curl but it seems to send 0 bytes of payload.

```
{ [5 bytes data]
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 1000)!
} [5 bytes data]
* We are completely uploaded and fine
{ [5 bytes data]
HTTP/2 200
apns-id: xxx-XXX-xxx
{ [0 bytes data]
100   256    0     0  100   256      0    387 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   387
* Connection #0 to host api.push.apple.com left intact
```

I'm trying using "com.notnoop.apns" library 1.0.0.Beta6 (and lower too) but no one notification was delivered to device.
Maybe I'm wrong something?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found! working with java 8, we need to add ALPN protocol to bootclasspath by **-Xbootclasspath/p:/path/to/the/alpn.jar** cos java 8 (and lower) don't support natively negotiation for handshake so requests are not successful.
Adding this command to VM options allows you to send push notifications but, for who want to choose another way, there is another library that **includes** this alpn protocol: pushy.
Easy to implement and less complex than notnoop.
I was able to send notifications using both library but in the end, I've choose pushy.
I consider this post closed!

Comment: Hi! I quick question, how can I send bulk notification using this? For example if I want to send a notification to 1000 devices.